# Memoir Class, \sidebar formatting

Tags: memoir, footnotes

In the `memoir` class, is there a way to get the `\sidebar` notes to be in paragraph style? I am looking for a similar effect that `fnpara` provides to footnotes.

I have included an image of what I would like my sidenote column to look like.

[image: Image of what I desire my sidenote column to look like.]

Comment: Related: [Sidenote formatting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78067/5764)

Comment: And by paragraph formatting you mean that the notes start from the top of the text block regardless of where they are made.

Comment: From my understanding, the `\sidebar` automatically starts the notes at the top of the text block. I have added an image of what I mean by paragraph style. The subsequent note will start on the same line as the previous note, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Does this come anywhere close to what you seek? (You may or may not want to reset the counter `sbrefs` in the `\showsidebar` invocation, as I did)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\edef\sbar{}
\newcounter{sbrefs}
\setcounter{sbrefs}{0}
\newcommand\addtosidebar[1]{%
\addtocounter{sbrefs}{1}%
$^\alph{sbrefs}$%
\edef\sbar{\sbar$^\alph{sbrefs}$#1 }%
}
\newcommand\showsidebar{%
\sidebar{\sbar}%
\edef\sbar{}%
\setcounter{sbrefs}{0}%
}
\begin{document}
In the beginning, etc. God created the heaven and the earth 
In the beginning, etc. God created the heaven and the earth 
In the beginning, etc. God created the heaven and the earth 
In the beginning, etc. God created the heaven and the earth%
\addtosidebar{Gn 1:1}
In the beginning, etc. God created the heaven and the earth 
In the beginning, etc. God created the heaven and the earth%
\addtosidebar{Ex 3:2; Ex 3:16}
In the beginning, etc. God created the heaven and the earth 
In the beginning, etc. God created the heaven and the earth%
\addtosidebar{Jn 3:16}
In the beginning, etc. God created the heaven and the earth 
In the beginning, etc. God created the heaven and the earth%
\addtosidebar{Mt 1:17}
In the beginning, etc. God created the heaven and the earth 
In the beginning, etc. God created the heaven and the earth 
\showsidebar

\end{document}
```

[image]