# how to return protected command with one argument already validated in latex/tex?

Tags: macros, lists, expansion

I want a command that will create an unevaluated bit of LaTeX/TeX code (to be evaluated at the end of an environment, but this is not necessary information) that has been created using an evaluated command.

## Here is an attempt at a working example created from my work:

```
\newcommand{\myNotes}{\protect\item apple}
\newcounter{noteCnt}
\newcommand{\TblMark}[1]{
  \stepcounter{noteCnt}
  \alph{noteCnt} %in this example, this is just printing a character at this location
  \makeatletter
  \g@addto@macro\myNotes{ \protect\item \alph{noteCnt} #1} %creating item list
  \makeatother}

%elsewhere in the latex file...
Hello, I am feeling very \TblMark{frustrated} about my lack of \Tex \TblMark{knowledge}.

Here is a list:

\myNotes
```

The problem is that when `myNotes` is expanded, the current value of `noteCnt` is used in the item list.  I want the item list to use the `noteCnt` value at the time when `\TblMark` was expanded.

## My intention was to create something like:

Hello, I am feeling very a about my lack of TeX b.

Here is a list:

- a frustrated
- b knowledge

## Instead, I get something like:

Hello, I am feeling very a about my lack of TeX b.

Here is a list:

- b frustrated
- b knowledge

Comment: Related: [Save current value of counter in a command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39999/5764)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some remarks first:

1. `\makeatletter` is required before code containing an `@` is read *for the first time*, so I don't really believe you code works as-is (it doesn't in my test ;-)
2. As the macro `\g@addto@macro` does not expand its input (as you noted), `\protect\item` has no use here (and might make trouble elsewhere).
3. I corrected some minor errors. Feel free to ask if you have further questions.
4. I replaced your `\g@addto@macro` (which globally adds unexpanded tokens to the end of a macro) by the construct `\xdef\myNotes{\unexpanded\expandafter{\myNotes}...}` which does the same, but expands the token list.
5. Now `\item` really needs to be protected (by `\noexpand`).
6. `\unexpanded{#1}` makes sure no unwanted expansions take place in the text argument.

Here's the modified MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\myNotes}{\protect\item apple}
\newcounter{noteCnt}
\newcommand{\TblMark}[1]
{%
  \stepcounter{noteCnt}%
  \alph{noteCnt}%in this example, this is just printing a character at this location
  \xdef\myNotes{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\myNotes}% previous contents of \myNotes, expanded once
    \noexpand\item % \item, unexpanded (one token)
    \alph{noteCnt} % expansion of counter `noteCnt' with space afterwards
    \unexpanded{#1}% argument #1, not expanded (several tokens)
  }% 
}


\begin{document}

%elsewhere in the latex file...
Hello, I am feeling very \TblMark{frustrated} about my lack of \TeX\ \TblMark{knowledge}.

Here is a list:

\begin{itemize}
\myNotes
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: @heikooberdiek Thanks for adding the code comments.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent response and @HeikoOberdiek for the comments.  One question about the `\unexpanded\expandafter{\myNotes}` line.  Does the `\expandafter` cause `\myNotes` to be expanded while the `\unexpanded` cause the `{` to remain?

Comment: @danelliottster More or less. `\unexpanded{...tokens...}` expands to `...tokens...` without any expansion. But we want `\myNotes` to be expanded exactly once, hence the `\expandafter`.