# Defining a command that conditionally defines/checks for counters

Tags: macros, conditionals, counters

In order to complete one custom package command I needed an internal macro, I called it `\@test@count{❬argument❭}`, and should accomplish the following:

1. Internally defines a new counter `\❬argument❭` and sets it to `1`.
2. Checks if the counter `\❬argument❭` is already defined, so it has to be conditionally dependent of the existence of previous counters:

   2.1. If `\❬argument❭` is already defined, then it'll not overwrite a *previous* value stored by `\❬argument❭` (as if it has saved its declaration) but it will advance it by `1`.

   2.2. If `\❬argument❭` isn't defined, then it'll simply create it.

If all of the above requirements are met, then the MWE (in this case `\@test@count{❬argument❭}` is used to obtain an identical task for the package command `\mycommand`):

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\makeatletter
\def\@test@count#1{%
 %mysterious (La)TeX sorcery should happen here
}
\def\mycommand[#1]#2{%
 \@test@count{#1}%
 This is the value of the counter~"#1":~\expandafter\the\csname #1\endcsname~#2\par%
}
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
%
\mycommand[myfoo]{lorem}
\mycommand[mybar]{ipsum}
\mycommand[mybaz]{dolor}
\mycommand[myfoo]{sit}
\mycommand[mybar]{amet}
\mycommand[myfoo]{consectetur}
\mycommand[mybaz]{adipisci}
%
\end{document}
```

should yield:

> [image]

The `text` has been inserted to show that the secondary argument can be filled without restrictions.

In the example, `\mycommand[myfoo]{...}` defines the counter `\myfoo` and sets it to `1`, because there are no other counters `\myfoo` declared before; then `\mycommand[mybar]{...}` defines `\mybar` and so forth. When `\mycommand[myfoo]{...}` is called again, then a `\@test@count{myfoo}` will test whether `\myfoo` is defined, in this case it yields "true" and then the counter is advanced by `1`. The same reasoning follows for any successive declaration of `mybar` and `mybaz`.

The rule for `\@test@count{myfoo}` will be similar to an allocation manager, because when a new counter is defined by `\mycommand[myfoo]{...}` it "saves" its previous value `\myfoo` until another `\myfoo` is declared: if this condition is met, then *`\myfoo` won't be overwritten*, but instead incremented.

So far I managed little to none progress to define `\@test@count#1{...}`, as this task requires [this kind of knowledge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39999/save-current-value-of-counter-in-a-command) that it's difficult for me to understand at the moment.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155776/check-if-counter-exists

Comment: @cgnieder Thanks, and with the help of the answer, I'll now be able to test some variations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The existence of a (LaTeX) counter can be tested with `\@ifundefined{c@<argument>}`:

```
\newcommand\andrea@test@count[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@#1}
    {% the counter doesn't exist
     \newcounter{#1}\setcounter{#1}{1}%
    }
    {% the counter exists
     \stepcounter{#1}%
    }%
}
```

Full example

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\makeatletter
\newcommand\andrea@test@count[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@#1}
    {% the counter doesn't exist
     \newcounter{#1}\setcounter{#1}{1}%
    }
    {% the counter exists
     \stepcounter{#1}%
    }%
}

\newcommand\mycommand[2]{%
 \andrea@test@count{#1}%
 This is the value of the counter~"#1":~\the\value{#1}~#2\par%
}
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
%
\mycommand{myfoo}{lorem}
\mycommand{mybar}{ipsum}
\mycommand{mybaz}{dolor}
\mycommand{myfoo}{sit}
\mycommand{mybar}{amet}
\mycommand{myfoo}{consectetur}
\mycommand{mybaz}{adipisci}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aah! Now I understand the "newcounter"/"stepcounter" criteria, and here I was searching for some complex solution with plain TeX... I haven't realized that those commands were in fact made to simplify and enhance therir usage. Many many thanks! ;)