# Creating the same counter in multiple files

Tags: counters, include

i am trying to create a counter (or better multiple independent counters) for a project with multiple people working on it over a long period of time.
The tex files are structured as

1. Main file
2. multiple Subfiles that may or may not are included and may or may not needs a counter

For the example we can assume there are 2 files and both are included and need a counter.

```
\documentclass{article}

  %ideally the main should not be altered, but if has to be done 

\begin{document}

 %main file include following text from file 1
Lorem
\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{1}
\themycounter\stepcounter{mycounter}
Ipsum


 %main file include following text from file 2 
Dolor
\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{1}
\themycounter\stepcounter{mycounter}
Sit 
\themycounter\stepcounter{mycounter}
Amet

\end{document}
```

This will create an error as the second `\newcounter{mycounter}` tries to create what already exists. 
What i tried so far:

- Putting the counter in the main-file, which works but is for now the least favorable solution
- Deleting the counter at the end of the file, but didnt find code to delete counters.
- Tried to adapt the solution from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201051/defining-a-command-that-conditionally-defines-checks-for-counters?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) question but failed misearbly as i dont understand how the `@`works

  ```
  \newcommand\andrea@test@count[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@#1}
   {% the counter doesn't exist
   \newcounter{#1}\setcounter{#1}{1}%
  }
  {% the counter exists
   \stepcounter{#1}%
  }%
  }
  ```

Does anyone has an idea on how to create the counter in each file? 
An additional but small questions is there an easier way to increase and use a counter than `\themycounter\stepcounter{mycounter}`?

Thank you

Comment: For `\andrea@test@count` and `\@ifundefined` you'd have to surround the code with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` which changes the category code of the `@` symbol to 11 (letters) and back to 12 (others). Best you put something like `\makeatletter\newcommand\MyNewCounter[1]{\@ifundefined{c@#1}{\newcounter{#1}\setcounter{#1}{1}}{\stepcounter{#1}}}\makeatother` in your preamble. Then each of you can use `\MyNewCounter` in the files to create as many counters as the used TeX engine allows you without worrying to define one two times.

Comment: And [welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: What shall the counter count here actually? Why do you need the same counter name again? Counters should be defined in the preamble of a document ideally, not somewhere in between, if possible. The title is incomplete, as well

Comment: it is very hard to understand your question as you refer to including files but your example just consists of a single document,

Comment: Thank you @Skillmon! The counter is needed to count some lines in a file. if it is a different name each time there is would be no issue, but it cant be guaranteed that there is a unique name each time. I felt like it would be easier to understand it this way than to write 3 different files. In the main file there is an `\input(file1.tex)` and the content of file1 is what i wrote after the comment

Comment: You could as well just use a prefix for all your counters (e.g. `\newcounter{FinnLines}` and he uses something like `\newcounter{OtherGuyLines}`) problem solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

This uses a modified `\include` - macro, prepending it with a test whether the counter is defined at all and defines it accordingly. At the end, the counter macro `\c@mycounter` is 'undefined'.

The prepending could be done with `\g@addto@macro`, but there is no easy way to put something at the end of the macro other than wrapping it in a 
macro, which is basically done here.

The macro `\showstepcounter` is meant for showing the counter value and stepping it afterwards.

Code for `fileone.tex` and `filetwo.tex` is equal

`fileone.tex`

```
Lorem

\showstepcounter{mycounter}


Ipsum
```

`Main document:`

The code for the modified `\include` and `\showstepcounter` should be placed in separated `.sty` file to make it available for all users that need this particular structure.

```
\documentclass{article}



\makeatletter
\let\l@tex@@include\include

\renewcommand{\include}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@mycounter}{%
    \newcounter{mycounter}%
    \setcounter{mycounter}{1}%
  }{%
    \setcounter{mycounter}{1}%
  }
  \l@tex@@include{#1}%
  \let\c@mycounter\relax
}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\showstepcounter}[1]{%
  \csname the#1\endcsname\stepcounter{#1}%
}



\begin{document}

\include{fileone}

\include{filetwo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Best regards and my compliments.- +1.

Comment: Great! Thank you for also adding the `showstepcounter`, which i find is a good way to make the code more readable

Comment: @Finn: I will post another version later one, which will save the counter value before `\include` and then restores the value back at the end. That's perhaps better than redefining counters all the while

Comment: Sorry, I upvoted it earlier. Done! Thank you!