# Collecting into a command values of a counter

Tags: counters, expansion

I am trying to collect into a command called `\drawtasks` a series of `\drawtask` commands that call TikZ. Every time I call `\wptask`, the command should increment a counter and append to `\drawtasks` a call to `\drawtask` with the current value counter. Unfortunately, when I finally call `\drawtasks`, I always get the last counter value. I've tried out solutions proposed in similar questions on here (e.g., [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39999/save-current-value-of-counter-in-a-command), but it just doesn't work: it seems that my problem is different in that I want to append a call to another command which should not be expanded. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\drawtask}[4]{
    \node[anchor=west] at (-2,-0.5 * #1 - 0.25) {Task #2} ;
    \filldraw[fill=green!20,draw=green!50!black] (#3 / 3,-0.5 * #1 - 0.15) rectangle (#4 / 3,-0.5 * #1 - 0.35) ;

}
\newcounter{wptaskcounter}
\setcounter{wptaskcounter}{0}
\newcommand{\drawtasks}{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\appendwptask}[4]{%
    \protected@edef\@tempa{#1}%
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\drawtasks\expandafter{%
        \drawtask{\@tempa}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
    }%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\wptask}[3]{%
    \appendwptask{\thewptaskcounter}{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    \stepcounter{wptaskcounter}%
}

\wptask{1.1}{0}{3}
\wptask{1.2}{3}{6}
\wptask{1.3}{6}{9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawtasks
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I'm really confused with the expansion rules of LaTeX and would really appreciate some help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you get a compilation error?

Comment: The funny thing is that I do if I compile it like this, but not if I replace \documentclass{article} with my own class that I created for the project. This seems to happen even if I add all the other packages I used in the class. And the class actually modifies "article", so I'm baffled by this behaviour too!

Comment: You're expanding `\drawtask` before the `{}` whereas you want to expand `\@tempa` and have `\drawtask` not be expanded, don't you?

Comment: I see. Would you mind telling me how exactly to achieve this? (I'm not really completely clear with how \expandafter works.)

Comment: I'm useless with expansion - I don't understand it at all. But the `\expandafter` just skips the next thing, which is the `{`, and expands the thing after, which is `\drawtask`. At least, that's what egreg says. I asked in a comment on the answer you linked to.

Comment: Maybe try `\expandafter{\expandafter\drawtask\expandafter{\@tempa}...` or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on egreg's comments on the answer you linked in the question, you might do it this way.

I always read `\expandafter<token 1><token 2>` as meaning something like *come back and expand `<token 1>` after expanding `<token 2>`* i.e. expand this next thing after the thing following it.

However, it seems instead to mean *expand `<token 2>` next and then come back to `<token 1>`* i.e. expand the thing after the next thing next.

In that case, what you want within the `\drawtasks` is for TeX to consider `\drawtask` only after looking at `\@tempa`. So you might try

```
\expandafter\drawtask\expandafter{\@tempa ...
```

which says to look at `\drawtask` only after expanding (looking at `\{` only after expanding `\@tempa`).

... er, I think. However, I'm almost certainly wrong.

Nonetheless,

```
\newcommand{\appendwptask}[4]{%
    \protected@edef\@tempa{#1}%
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\drawtasks\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\drawtask\expandafter{\@tempa}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
    }%
}
```

seems to work, I think.

[image: accumulated tasks]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\drawtask}[4]{
    \node[anchor=west] at (-2,-0.5 * #1 - 0.25) {Task #2} ;
    \filldraw[fill=green!20,draw=green!50!black] (#3 / 3,-0.5 * #1 - 0.15) rectangle (#4 / 3,-0.5 * #1 - 0.35) ;

}
\newcounter{wptaskcounter}
\setcounter{wptaskcounter}{0}
\newcommand{\drawtasks}{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\appendwptask}[4]{%
    \protected@edef\@tempa{#1}%
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\drawtasks\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\drawtask\expandafter{\@tempa}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
    }%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\wptask}[3]{%
    \appendwptask{\thewptaskcounter}{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    \stepcounter{wptaskcounter}%
}

\wptask{1.1}{0}{3}
\wptask{1.2}{3}{6}
\wptask{1.3}{6}{9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawtasks
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than doing it this way I would make `\wptask` generate a comma separated list and then have `\drawtasks` loop over the list using [tikz/pgf](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)'s `\foreach` command.

Doing it this way, your MWE produces:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\let\wptasklist\relax% will become a comma separate list of the task parameters
\newcommand{\wptask}[3]{%  \addtask might be a better name:)
   \ifx\wptasklist\relax\def\wptasklist{#1/#2/#3}% first task
   \else\xdef\wptasklist{\wptasklist,#1/#2/#3}% add a task
   \fi%
}

\newcommand\drawtasks{% loop over \wptasklist and draw the tasks
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \foreach \a/\b/\c [count=\n] in \wptasklist {% loop over task list
        \node[anchor=west] at (-2,-0.5 * \n - 0.25) {Task \a};
        \filldraw[fill=green!20,draw=green!50!black] 
                 (\b/3,-0.5*\n-0.15) rectangle (\c/3,-0.5*\n-0.35);
     }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\wptask{1.1}{0}{3}
\wptask{1.2}{3}{6}
\wptask{1.3}{6}{9}

\begin{document}

    \drawtasks

\end{document}
```

Hopefully the code is fairly self-explanatory. Notice that there are no expansion issues, except for the use of `\xdef` to add to the task list, and there is no need for a counter because you can use `[count=\n]` as part of the `\foreach` loop to  determine the "task number".

There is one caveat, which doesn't seem to apply in your use-case: any of the parameters to `\wptask` that contain a slash `/` will need to be put inside braces `{.../...}`.

**EDIT**

Here is a second solution that is closer to the OP's MWE. It uses `\eappto` from
the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package, which is a robust and general implementation of the `\appendwptask` macro in the question, together with `\noexpand`. For me at least, this gives a is more intuitive way of coping with these expansion issues. The output is the same as above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\drawtask}[4]{
    \node[anchor=west] at (-2,-0.5 * #1 - 0.25) {Task #2} ;
    \filldraw[fill=green!20,draw=green!50!black] (#3 / 3,-0.5 * #1 - 0.15) rectangle (#4 / 3,-0.5 * #1 - 0.35) ;

}
\newcounter{wptaskcounter}% set to 0 by default
\newcommand{\drawtasks}{}
\newcommand{\wptask}[3]{%
    \eappto\drawtasks{\noexpand\drawtask{\thewptaskcounter}{#1}{#2}{#3}}% append to \drawtasks
    \stepcounter{wptaskcounter}%
}

\wptask{1.1}{0}{3}
\wptask{1.2}{3}{6}
\wptask{1.3}{6}{9}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawtasks
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you want to "accumulate many things" then using a key-val system like [pgfkeys](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) might be a better option...well, except for the initial learning curve:)

Comment: Thank you, this works well. However, I was going to accumulate other things than just the \drawtask command; for example, I'd like to add separators and so on. Thus, the structure of things in the list won't be homogeneous, which is why accumulating through a command seemed more appropriate. Thanks nevertheless, it's a nice solution!

Comment: @Boris It is difficult to anticipate what you want to do if it is not illustrated by your [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). You should either extend your MWE or ask another question.  Btw, the "correct" way to thank is to up-vote and assign green ticks when appropriate:)

Comment: @Boris You might find it helpful t look at the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/) as it provides a number of "tools" to make expansion easier. An approach using pgf keys is also worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\unexpanded`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\providecommand{\expandonce}[1]{%
  \unexpanded\expandafter{#1}%
} % etoolbox already provides this

\newcommand{\drawtask}[4]{
  \node[anchor=west] at (-2,-0.5 * #1 - 0.25) {Task #2} ;
  \filldraw[fill=green!20,draw=green!50!black]
    (#3 / 3,-0.5 * #1 - 0.15) rectangle (#4 / 3,-0.5 * #1 - 0.35) ;
}
\newcounter{wptaskcounter}
\setcounter{wptaskcounter}{0}
\newcommand{\drawtasks}{}

\newcommand{\appendwptask}[4]{%
  \edef\drawtasks{%
    \expandonce{\drawtasks}%
    \expandonce{\drawtask{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\wptask}[3]{%
  \expandafter\appendwptask\expandafter{\the\value{wptaskcounter}}{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  \stepcounter{wptaskcounter}%
}

\wptask{1.1}{0}{3}
\wptask{1.2}{3}{6}
\wptask{1.3}{6}{9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\drawtasks
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In this way, `\expandonce{\drawtasks}` will only expand once `\drawtasks`, so to get its previous value; similarly, `\expandonce{\drawtask{...}{...}{...}{...}}` will perform the first level expansion of `\drawtask`, leaving the replacement text (with parameters replaced by the arguments). You also need to expand the value of the counter.

[image]

A much cleaner version can be obtained by using `expl3` (via `xparse` for the interface):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\drawtask}[4]{
  \node[anchor=west] at (-2,-0.5 * #1 - 0.25) {Task #2} ;
  \filldraw[fill=green!20,draw=green!50!black]
    (#3 / 3,-0.5 * #1 - 0.15) rectangle (#4 / 3,-0.5 * #1 - 0.35) ;
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g_boris_drawtasks_tl
\int_new:N \g_boris_wptask_int

\NewDocumentCommand{\drawtasks}{}
 {
  \tl_use:N \g_boris_drawtasks_tl
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\wptask}{mmm}
 {
  \boris_append_wptask:fnnn
    { \int_to_arabic:n { \g_boris_wptask_int } }
    { #1 }
    { #2 }
    { #3 }
  \int_gincr:N \g_boris_wptask_int
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \boris_append_wptask:nnnn
 {
  \tl_gput_right:No \g_boris_drawtasks_tl
   {
    \drawtask{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \boris_append_wptask:nnnn { f }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\wptask{1.1}{0}{3}
\wptask{1.2}{3}{6}
\wptask{1.3}{6}{9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\drawtasks
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

We take care of getting the expanded version of the counter's value by defining a variant `f` (full expansion).